# Auto looping filmstrip not working

Tags: php

I am trying different things with PHP to create a web site from my photographic work. There are a number of off the shelf galleries, but this is not what I am looking for.

I have the bases,, which is photos held in folder with names that relate to content. The names of the folders are displayed in a table and when the name is clicked the idea is to open another page that will display a slide show of all the photos in the selected folder.

Currently using:

```
$Dir =$_GET[file];

$files = glob("images/$Dir/*.jpg");

for ($i=0; $i<=count($files); $i++)
{   
  $num = $files[$i];
  echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" />'."<br /><br />";
}
```

This opens the correct folder and displays the first photo in a `<div>`, tag but will not produce the filmstrip I wish for.

Comment: Make proper question structure.

Answer (score 0):

> This open the correct folder and displays the first photo

I'm surprised you even get the first photo displayed!

Your current code *can't work at all*, because:

- `$files = glob($pattern)` expects `$pattern` and returns each `$files[$i]` as *physical paths*
- `<img src="source">` expects `source` to be an *url*
- so writing `'<img src=" . $files[$i] . '">'` has no sense: it assigns a physical path where an url is expected
- more over, your initial `$files = glob("images/$Dir/*.jpg");` can't return anything, since `images/` is not the root of any path in your system.

Instead you must:

1. correctly look for your folder contents using its physical path in `glob()`
2. when using the results, "translate" each physical path into the corresponding url (depending on your site localization)

To achieve this translation you can use `dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])`, which gives you the complete physical path to your script: you'll have to prepend it to the `glob()` pattern, then drop it from the found files path.

Finally you can write something like this:

```
$site_root = dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
$root_length = strlen($site_root) + 1;

if ($files = glob("$site_root/images/$_GET[file]/*.jpg")) {
  foreach ($files as $file) {   
    echo '<img src="' . substr($file, $root_length) . '" alt="random image" /><br /><br />';
  }
}
```

Note that:

- `+ 1` in `$root_length` is needed to also drop the "/", so keeping the image url relative to the site root
- using `foreach()` to iterate found files is simpler than `for ()`
- `if ($files...)` is to avoid firing an error on `foreach` in the case of `glob()` returning `false`